# How to merge time series dataframes by unix timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes both containing time series data. Both have two columns, one being Unix time in ms and the other holding a value. Tyhe two dataframes have differing sampling frequencies.

DATAFRAME1:

```
    time [s/1000]     DATA1 
0   1558970242000   -0.019531
1   1558970242025   -0.078125
2   1558970242050   -0.058594
3   1558970242075   -0.054688
4   1558970242100   -0.046875
.         .              .
.         .              .
.         .              .
```

DATAFRAME2:

```
    time [s/1000]     DATA2 
0   1558970242000   -0.054567
1   1558970242050   -0.073567
2   1558970242100   -0.954543
.         .              .
.         .              .
.         .              .
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
    time [s/1000]      DATA1        DATA2
0   1558970242000   -0.019531     -0.054567      **hold data for 25ms
1   1558970242025   -0.078125     -0.054567
2   1558970242050   -0.058594     -0.073567
3   1558970242075   -0.054688     -0.073567
5   1558970242100   -0.046875     -0.954543
.         .              .            .
.         .              .            .  
.         .              .            .
```

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to implement this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you need a data structure with a key and a value which is a complex type. Assuming the times are exactly the same they should pass any number check or string check for equality. A simple tuple and hash would allow you to iterate on the largest of the data-sets, check if the key exists or None, and ensure that a tuple of data1 and data2 are created for each unique period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great use case for `merge_asof` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)):

```
df
            time     DATA1
0  1558970242000 -0.019531
1  1558970242025 -0.078125
2  1558970242050 -0.058594
3  1558970242075 -0.054688
4  1558970242100 -0.046875

df2
            time     DATA2
0  1558970242000 -0.054567
1  1558970242050 -0.073567
2  1558970242100 -0.954543

pd.merge_asof(df, df2, on='time')

            time     DATA1     DATA2
0  1558970242000 -0.019531 -0.054567
1  1558970242025 -0.078125 -0.054567
2  1558970242050 -0.058594 -0.073567
3  1558970242075 -0.054688 -0.073567
4  1558970242100 -0.046875 -0.954543
```

#### Explanation

For each row in the *left* DataFrame, the default `direction='backward'` merge selects the *last* row from the right DataFrame whose 'on' key is *less than or equal to* the left's key.

In your case, this means that each row in the resulting DataFrame contains the value of `DATA2` **as of** the timestamp in the row. "As of this row's timestamp, here's the last observed value of `DATA2`."

Answer (score 3):

Reindex the second dataframe to have the same frequency as the first:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('time [s/1000]')
df2 = df2.set_index('time [s/1000]')
result = df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill'))
```